# Is there an IntelliJ Keymapping plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am an old IntelliJ user, now working on a project that requires Eclipse.
I don't mind learning the Eclipse default keyboard shortcuts where they exist, but so many operations don't have shortcuts assigned (grrrr!)

I was wondering if there is any plugin that would automatically assign the IntelliJ defaults to any action that does not already have a mapping?

As an alternative I guess I could also use a plugin that just wipes out all of the Eclipse defaults and replaces them with the IntelliJ versions.

Or do I have to just go and manually replace them all one by one :( ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The [IdeaKeyScheme plugin](https://code.google.com/p/ideakeyscheme/) was just developed by one guy that wanted the same thing. Source and binary are available. I haven't tried it myself, but many people use it with great success. It seems to be the only thing out there.

If you're concerned about keyboard mappings, the [Key Promoter plugin for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mousefeed) (known as MouseFeed) will be a big help, too. There's also an [IntelliJ version](http://plugins.jetbrains.net/plugin?pr=webide&pluginId=4455). I highly recommend this plugin for productivity enhancement.

---

**Installation and enabling [IdeaKeyScheme plugin](https://code.google.com/p/ideakeyscheme/)**

1. For Eclipse: add jar file to `eclipse/dropins/plugins` folder.
2. Restart Eclipse.
3. Open *Window* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Keys* and select the scheme *"Intellij Idea"*.

Comment: Sorry, you have it reversed. My fingers are very used to the IntelliJ shortcuts. I am now having to use Eclipse, and wishing there were an IntelliJ keyboard mapping, parallel to the Eclipse keymaps provided by intelliJ. And as I said, I don't mind learning the Eclipse shortcuts, but so many operations are not mapped in Eclipse. What's up with that?

Comment: Ryan - Your plugin is awesome, just what the doctor ordered. Can you modify your original answer and I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Moved my comments into the answer.

Comment: copying the jar to the plugin directory of eclipse didn't work! how should i enable it in right way? 'll the plugin comes with both intellij and eclipse shortcuts (eg.view is specific to eclipse)

Comment: @Dineshkumar Open Preferences General>Keys and enable the Scheme "Intellij Idea"

Comment: I went to the mousefeed site and it apparently is a pron site now.

Comment: For Eclipse Mars: 
add jar file to "eclipse/dropins/plugins" folder

Comment: The key scheme did show in Neon but it doesn't do the most basic shortcuts like move up/down or yank :(

Comment: I downloaded this plugin for Eclipse Neon. At first sight it seems to works.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Had a quick test with Eclipse Oxygen. Basic IntelliJIDEA shortcuts are working. Thank you, a lot indeed!

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Stewart, the plugins works amazing. One issue I faced is for the search everything option(For intellij the shortcut is Double Shift). The plugin doesnt change this shortcut. Its still ctrl + SHift + R. Is there any option for changing this to Double shift?

Comment: Currently working on Eclipse Photon without any problems. Used all the basic shortcuts.

Comment: Working for Eclipse Oxygen too ! Just add the jar as explained by @RyanStewart

Answer (score 6):

I wanted the same thing since I predominantly use IntelliJ IDEA. Found this on the eclipse market place and up to now it has the same keymappings.

Activate it by going to : 
***Window >> Preferences >> General >> Keys*** : change the scheme to : IntelliJ IDEA

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/intellij-idea-keymap-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You may add a key map as described here:
http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/intellij_idea_key_scheme_for

The plugin itself is:
http://jroller.com/santhosh/resource/IdeaKeyScheme.jar

You need just to put the jar file into eclipse/plugins and restart IDE.  It works on Luna just fine!

Comment: It didn't work when I put it in `eclipse/plugins`. I had to place it in `eclipse/dropins/plugins` (I created the folder in `dropins`) then it worked.  Hopefully that helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Open your eclipse software
Drag and drop `Installer` button from

> https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/intellij-idea-keymap-eclipse

in your always open eclipse
and that's all

Answer (score -4):

It turns out that in IntelliJ, by default you can choose a keymap scheme. So you can just apply the Eclipse Shortcuts without any plugin. 
Just press CTRl + `

Details here 
http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/getting-started-with-intellij-idea-as-an-eclipse-user/4/

Comment: Well the other way around. I was being forced to use Eclipse