# Any way to use Eclipse more like Intellij in terms of shortcuts?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am starting a new course about Spring in Java, so far I only used IntelliJ IDE so I have nothing to really compare it too, but in this new course and the instructor is using Eclipse. 
I can get used to the different shortcuts (sysout instead of sout and so on) but I really got used to the IntelliJ pop-up shortcut, when you start typing and have this pop-out window to complete shortcuts. And in eclipse, I need to press ctrl + space to see this thing.
Is there any way to make it automatic like in IntelliJ?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it is the closest I've got to get Eclipse keymap like IntelliJIDEA's: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/intellij-idea-keymap-eclipse

Comment: Here you will get what you are asking for, may be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105249/is-there-an-intellij-keymapping-plugin-for-eclipse

Comment: leal how do I install it?